# system tray app to control windows service

Tags: windows-services, system-tray

I have created a windows service to kick off a daily process and I also have created a system tray app (in other words, a win form app that displays system tray icon with a context menu) to control this windows service. The context menu also shows the result of the last run and the runtime for the next time (there is a random element to the start time a la anacrontab)

The issue I'm struggling with is, how do I make sure that the system tray app runs when:

The service is installed
  &
 a user logs in (remotely)

I know about the Startup folder, but it seems a little bit noddy. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want that system tray application to run when none is logged in???

i think you should try with startup thing and if you found any problem then go for work around.

i am also working on similar thing but i have different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation, and yes, Startup folder is still unreliable in 2021.

From my experience, **Windows Task Scheduler** is the most reliable way. You can configure it to run anything on Logon, or on one of many other supported events:

[image]